# Printing the ping result in a simple format like "10ms"

Tags: debian, text-processing, timestamps, ping

Whenever I run "ping -c 1 www.google.com", I get this result:

```
PING www.google.com (xxx.xx.xxx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from xxxxxxxx-xx-xxxxxxxxxx.net (xxx.xx.xxx.xxx): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 
time=25.8 ms

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 25.816/25.816/25.816/0.000 ms
```

However, I'd like to print out the ping in a simple format like this:

```
[23:00:25] 25.8 ms
```

How can I achieve this? So far I've tried

```
ping -c 1 www.google.com | grep -oP '(?<=time\s/)w+' > ping.txt
```

to print the ping without the time, but as you probably guessed, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ping -c 1 www.google.com | awk 'NR==2{print strftime("[%T]",systime()),substr($8,6),"ms"}'
```

Grabs the current time using `systime()` and formats it into %T presentation (hh:mm:ss) using `strftime`.  Then prints the relevant part of field 8, to strip off the `time=` nonsense.

Example

```
ping -c 1 www.google.com | awk 'NR==2{print strftime("[%T]",systime()),substr($8,6),"ms"}'
[21:32:05] 1.03 ms
```

Comment: Tried it out, got this:

    'awk: line 2: function strftime never defined
    awk: line 2: function systime never defined

Am I missing some packages?

Comment: I'm on gnu awk 3.1.7, check your own using `awk --version`.  I see that `strftime` functionality was introduced into gnu awk 2.13.  Perhaps you're using an older version?

Comment: Ahh, I found the problem - since I'm on Raspbian (Debian for Raspberry PI), all I've got is mawk 1.3.3... I'll have to get gnu awk.

Comment: I just installed gnu awk; your solution works perfectly. (GNU Awk 4.1.1) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another ***awk*** approach:

```
ping -c1 www.google.com | awk -F'=' 'NR==2{ print strftime("[%T]",systime()),$NF; exit}'
[01:35:47] 41.5 ms
```

---

- `-F'='` - custom field separator
- `$NF` - last field value
- `exit` - to stop processing input immediately on the 2nd record